# Update Context in Odoo Controller (request.env.context)

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to update request context,

```
request.env.context
```

At the moment I got this dictionary

```
{'lang': u'en_US', 'tz': False, 'uid': 21}
```

I wanna update *lang* key, and expected output of

```
request.env.context
{'lang': 'de_DE', 'tz': False, 'uid': 21}
```

Any idea how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
context = request.env.context.copy()
context.update({'lang': u'en_CA'})
request.env.context = context
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works well for me, I am guessing that you are working with a pos.order model

```
pos_order = request.env['pos.order'].with_context(
    lang='de_DE')
```